# Keras fit_generator doesn't see all of the data

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a convolutional neural netwrok for a tables of 0 and 1. The size of the image is 7*6 and the number of filters are 15. Since the dataset is rather large, I am trying to train it with fit_generator functions. Here is the code

```
model.fit_generator(
generator=data_generator(ml_mode='train'),
samples_per_epoch=12800,#int(self.num_points['train']['pos'] * 2 * self.configs['training']['train_data_fraction_per_epoch']),
nb_epoch=100,
callbacks=None,
verbose=1,
validation_data=data_generator(ml_mode='test'),
nb_val_samples = 1280,
initial_epoch=0,
class_weight = my_class_weight
)
```

and here is the implementation of my data_generator:

```
model.fit_generator(
generator=data_generator(ml_mode='train'),
samples_per_epoch=12800,#int(self.num_points['train']['pos'] * 2 * self.configs['training']['train_data_fraction_per_epoch']),
nb_epoch=100,
callbacks=None,
verbose=1,
validation_data=data_generator(ml_mode='test'),
nb_val_samples = 1280,
initial_epoch=0,
class_weight = my_class_weight
)
```

I put prints  to check how many lines it reads and I got the count of 25k while my data is 130k lines. Can anybody help me understand what is the potential problem here or what am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it myself and I think it might be useful to share what I have observed.

samples_per_epoch is the number of times that algorithm continue from yield before forming data. 
I fixed it by setting this parameter to my batch_size and nb_epoch to the value of data_size/ batch_size.

Keras reads 10 examples first then it tries to find a best available core which was a little confusing to me.

Best